# Probability of card hand value

Tags: combinatorics

My problem is;

I have a deck of 60 cards, made of any number of cards with values between 0 and 7.
I draw four cards.

I would like to know the probability of my total hand value being 0,1,2,3,4....28
So i can plot this on a graph.

I started off with
a= total number of cards worth 0

b= " worth 1

c= " worth 2

d= " worth 3

e= " worth 4

f= " worth 5

g= " worth 6

h= " worth 7

x= 60

Probability for total of 0 = aC4/xC4

" of 1 = aC3*bC1/xC4

" of 2 = aC2*bC2/xC4 + aC3*cC1/xC4

But there is a fair number of combinations and this feels incredibly messy.

Any thoughts on how to make this simpler?
Thanks.

Comment: 4 times 7 is 28 ... so either there's only 3 cards worth 7, or you failed to acknowledge the highest score possible.

Comment: You're right, for some reason i only calculated for 6 being the max number. Havnt had my morning coffee. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: base 7 sum of digits...

Comment: a 55 digit number of possible decks probably infeasible to even try them all.